# Client-side MV* - Should the model have a save method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, knockout.js, ember.js

So this is a generic pattern question but one I have been going back and forth with for some time.

**Should a model have a save method in MV*?**

I often jump back and forth between Knockout, Ember, and sometimes even Angular but one of the persistent questions I always have is should the model have a save method on it's class or prototype that knows how to save changes to reduce dependencies around the application on services (aka the model has a service for saving that all of the other view models / controllers inherit by knowing about the model) or should there be a service that each of the view models / controllers depend on that has a specific method for saving changes to the object?

*Example JavaScript pseudo-code*

```
var person = new Model.Person();
person.name = 'Bill';
person.save();
```

vs

```
var personService = require('services/person.service');
var person = new Model.Person();
person.name = 'Bill';
personService.save(person);
```

Both accomplish the same purpose of saving the person but in Example 1 the view model / controller doesn't know about the service or how it is implemented only that if you want to change a person, you save it.  In example two obviously we have to know about not only the way to save it but how the save is implemented.

## Please read this before you answer -

I realize that this is an opinion-based question but if you can back up your opinion with facts it will be factual, so please have references to back up any claims so that this is not closed as 'Primarily opinion based'

Comment: I believe angular's [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) pretty much drives you to the 1st design (assuming `person.save()` means "do an HTTP POST to a REST resource").

Comment: Sorry, but this *is* opinion-based, and you can't shield your question from closure by admitting this in the question. There's no good definitive answer to this question, you're just trying to incite discussion. Even if it weren't closed because it's opinion-based, it should be closed because it's way too broad. We can't possible answer this for every use case.

Comment: @meagar OP is talking about two very specific patterns here, and where each is useful and not. In my opinion, this has been a topic of research, and there are definitive answers to what advantages and disadvantages each has. The only opinion based part is which to actually use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the pattern (and not at all opinion based imo).

- Your first example: A domain object having a `.save` method is called an [ActiveRecord](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) (also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)).
- Your second example: A mapper between the data mapping and domain layers is called a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) (also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx))

#### Active Record pattern

Quoting Fowler:

> An object that wraps a row in a database table or view, encapsulates the database access, and adds domain logic on that data.

The ActiveRecord pattern generally excels at prototyping, and is a good idea sometimes in very small applications where there exists a 1-1 mapping between objects and DB rows. Generally, you want to separate the logic of persisting an object and the logic of an actual domain object, since they are inherently different responsibilities.

This is one of the simplest ways to logically handle the persistence of data.

[image]

For example, this is what Backbone models and collections do with their `sync()` method. Which causes them to persist to the server. It's often the reason you see larger Backbone applications not use `sync()` altogether in favor of implementing their own adapters. After all, in the Backbone world it forces a 1-1 mapping between your REST API and your domain objects, effectively making your domain objects and data transfer objects the same which can grow hard to maintain as your application grows.

#### Repository Pattern

Quoting Fowler again:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

A repository is generally a better design pattern for larger applications since it removes the persistence logic from your domain object, so it does better [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Implementation wise, a repository usually looks like this:
[image: Repository]

However, to its users a repository might look like:

[image]

As any abstraction, another object for a responsibility has some overhead, however - as an app grows it starts to pay off. If you create a `$resource` with Angular and wrap it in a service that maps these objects from the db query to your domain objects (your data mapper) and then query that service like a collection - that's a repository for you.

Comment: FWIW, Using repositories for data access [is bloat waiting to happen](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/11/wither-the-repository/). I'm for the abstraction, but I prefer using a command pattern now.  something like  `var savePersonCommand = new SavePersonCommand(); savePersonCommand.person = person; savePersonCommand.execute();` .. or hell, even just a function as a service in Angular would be fine.

Comment: @blesh I enjoy Jimmy Bogard articles (that blog in general) just like the next guy - but his criticism is about how people changed the pattern, not the Fowler pattern I present here. I also believe that language features like LINQ change the appraoch to these abstractions in the .NET world. In the JS world, I've noticed query builders (some SQL agnostic) starting to emerge for complicated queries (I see this from the promises side and resource management), however - I'm yet to see a client side project benefiting from the pattern you describe. More reading on this in JS would be appreciated :)

Comment: Fair enough, I've just been a part of some very large JS UI applications that utilized the Repository Pattern, and it did eventually end up in classes with very, very low cohesion. I'm sure if you work with rockstar JS developers, this probably isn't an issue, as they'll most likely stick to consistent patterns. Languages with strong-typing and interfacing I think make bloating repositories slightly more painful, so it's less apt to happen there. In JS, it's very, very easy to add *"just one more"* method to your repository for that *"special case"*. I'm leary of them in general.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer in my personal opinion would be your second version.  I typically think that the viewmodel on the client is basically a bag of data or properties.  Services are used to persist/get those viewmodels to/from the server, and the controller is responsible for consuming the service methods and rendering the view.  In the Angular.js world directives would handle any DOM-specific behavior, but I think that ultimately the events that happen as a result of UI interaction (saving, validation, etc.) would be handled by the controller (perhaps by calling a service method).

I formulated this opinion when I started using Angular.js, and was going through their developer [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).  The short of it is:

Use controllers to:

- Set up the initial state of the viewmodel object
- Add behavior to the viewmodel object

Do not use controllers to:

- Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic.
- Format input
- Filter output
- Manage the life-cycle of other components (for example, to create
  service instances).

Use services to organize and share code and state across your app.